# How to implement AngularJS MVC

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

I am a beginner and keen to  learn AngularJS. Problem is I have gone through several youtube tutorials and online content but no where I am able to find proper implementation of MVC architecture in angular. As controllers are recking my head.

I am trying to build my profile as a front end developer for better opportunities and starting small by self learning whatever I can through online resources.

Help and guidance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why not use a scaffolding tool such as Yeoman https://yeoman.io/generators/?

Comment: The [AngularJS Tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) is helpful. A great way to get introduced to AngularJS is to work through this tutorial, which walks you through the construction of an AngularJS web app. The app you will build is a catalog that displays a list of Android devices, lets you filter the list to see only devices that interest you, and then view details for any device.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said in your post you are confused about the controller portion I will explain what it is. A controller in AngularJS sits underneath a view and **controls** what the view is doing. Here is a small example taken from the [docs:](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02)

```
<html ng-app="phonecatApp">
<head>
  ...
  <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="PhoneListController">

  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="phone in phones">
      <span>{{phone.name}}</span>
      <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the view. Lets break this down!

1. You will see the `ng-controller="PhoneListController`. This is declaring the controller for this view.
2. Next you will see `ng-repeat="phone in phones"`. Think of this as a for loop. The loop variable is called phone and it is iterating over the array called phones which is declared in the controller can be defined here:

`var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', []);`

```
phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListController', function PhoneListController($scope) {
  $scope.phones = [
    {
      name: 'Nexus S',
      snippet: 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.'
    }, {
      name: 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi',
      snippet: 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'
    }, {
      name: 'MOTOROLA XOOM™',
      snippet: 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'
    }
  ];
});
```

Here is the controller! This is what **controls** the view. Lets break this one down as well!

1. `var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', []);` essentially pulling an instance of the `phonecatApp` module into your file. Think of the module as a container. You can add things to the container like controllers, services and various dependencies.
2. `phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListController', function PhoneListController($scope)` this line is adding a new controller to the module called `PhoneListController` remember when we used the `ng-controller="PhoneListController` directive in the view? The `$scope` parameter allows us to access the variables on the view like the `phones` variable we talked about.
3. `$scope.phones` here is how we declare a variable we intend on using in the view. When we add `$scope.` infront of a variable we are now able to access it in the view. You will notice that `$scope.phones` is an array of objects.

When using `ng-repeat` it is expecting an array of object because when we use the loop variable we talked about we can access that objects properties on the view! This can be seen here!

```
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="phone in phones">
      <span>{{phone.name}}</span>
      <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

This is accessing each object in the `phones` array and assigning that object to a variable called `phone` then we are able to output the properties of the `phone` object by using dot-notation!

All in all, this  `ng-repeat` is creating a new `li` element for each object in the `phones` array which was declared using the `$scope` notation! Now this can be extremely powerful! You can do something like this!

```
$scope.name = "Marcus"
```

Then in the view I could:

```
<p>{{name}}</p>
```

Then the view would show whatever the `name` variable is in my controller!